# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `user_tbl` set `remember_token` = twR4

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, logout

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `user_tbl` set `remember_token` = twR4isCzOsVYw4ODV87rC5hdLwAkhHuB8REorcfZe8uA3jlUNISHzT34oZlc, `updated_at` = 2016-08-16 12:40:05 where `id` = 1)
```

my logout code here:

```php
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->intended('login');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `updated_at` column into your SQL table `user_tbl`. If you do not wish to use it. you may also turn off `timestamps` within your model.

> By default, Eloquent expects `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the `$timestamps` property on your model to false

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent